# django form to apply for designed html elements

Tags: html, css, django, django-forms

I hve this html file:

```
<form method='POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name='foo'/>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>

</form>
```

Now, imagine this form has css atributes behind, I just want a form which would configure some inputs. For an example. The field is required, the min length is 10 chars, etc etc.

How could i approach that with Django forms?

is the something like:

```
from django import forms

class inputform(forms.Form):
    input_line = forms.CharField(max_length=20, min_length=10, name='foo')
```

how would i apply that to vies.py and how to get errors out to html?

Would appreciate your reply.

Comment: Did you go through this yet? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/ . Let me know if you have more specific questions.

Comment: Of course I did. But as you can see, I don't use labels in my case and I am not sure how to connect forms with html. I really don't understand the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this.

```
class inputForm(forms.Form):
    input_line = forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'input-field form-control'}))



    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cleaned_data = super(inputForm, self).clean()
        my_input = self.cleaned_data.get("input_line")
        if not my_input:
            raise forms.ValidationError('This field is required')
        if len(my_input) < 10:
            raise forms.ValidationError('the min length is 10 character')
        return cleaned_data
```

the clean() method is used for validating input from form.